# How to Get Contact Form Working

Tags: php, html

Okay so I am fairly new to web designing. How do I get the contact form on my current theme to work? This is the current html.

I need to know how to code the PHP file; is this correct?

```
<div class="form row-fluid clearfix">
    <div class="field span5">
        <label>Your name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="req" placeholder="Placeholder text..." />
    </div>
    <div class="field span5">
        <label>Your email:</label>
        <input type="email" value="" class="req" />
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field full">
        <label>Your comment:</label>
        <textarea class="span12" cols="2" rows="7"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button class="extruded"><span>Submit</span></button>
</div>

<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: iclear'; 
$to = 'sales@tangledindesign.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
?>
```

And how do I link the PHP file for that contact form?

Comment: hey your input type does not have any id ior name ..you need to google it

Comment: you can start from this tutorial http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1**

Wrap your fields with a form HTML element that has its action property set to your php processing page

**Step 2**

Name the form fields according to what the php file expects

**Step 3**

Add some validation

**Step 4**

Submit and test

**Example**

**HTML**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$first_name=$_POST["first_name"];
if($first_name=="John")
{
  echo "Hi John!";
}
else
{
   echo "Sorry Buddy, Don't really know you";
}
?>
```

**Note**

The reason why i did not provide you a full solution is that you mentioned you are a newbie in that programming, and it would be injustice to just solve your problem and not guide you how to do it

Comment: **WARNING!** You're passing unfiltered, unvalidated user input right back out. This can create a [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability, easily allowing malicious users to hijack your site for their own purposes. Please add appropriate validation to user input and filtering on output of user-provided data.  Yes, this applies even when building demo code.  *Especially* demo code.  Never underestimate the power of copy-paste "developers."

Comment: Note taken! updated to add a small check so as it incorporates your suggestion and yet remains simple enough for a beginner to understand

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your HTML with the  tag, and don't forget to get include the submit button:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post"> 
  <div class="form row-fluid clearfix">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Then here is the php (process.php) file to get all values from your HTML form:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$from = 'From: iclear'; 
$to = 'sales@tangledindesign.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
<?php
$toaddress ="youremail@domain.com" //change to your email address
$error ="";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
    $name=$_POST['name'] ;
    $email=$_POST['email'] ;
    $comment=$_POST['comment'] ;
        if(!isset($name) || $name==""){
             $error .="Please Enter your name <br/>";
        }elseif (!isset($email) || $email==""){
              $error .="Please Enter your email Address.<br/>";
        }elseif(!isset($comment) || $comment==""){
              $error .="Please Enter your Comments.<br/>";
        }
   if ($error ==""){
       mail($toaddress,"Contact form",$comment)
   }

}
?>

<?php echo  $error ;?>
<form  method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='news_form' name='post_form' >
<div class="form row-fluid clearfix">
    <div class="field span5">
        <label>Your name:</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" value="" class="req" placeholder="Placeholder text..." />
    </div>
    <div class="field span5">
        <label>Your email:</label>
        <input type="email" value="" class="req" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field full">
        <label>Your comment:</label>
        <textarea class="span12" cols="2" rows="7" name="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: how to I get the form to ensure all forms are complete and send me an email?

Comment: Check the edited code it will check all fields are complete and send email .